# Межпроцессное взаимодействие не зависящее от платформы и языка

Tags: c#

Нужна рекомендация по организации межпроцессного взаимодействия:

- Что-то не зависящее от операционной системы, ну или чтобы были рабочие реализации хотя бы под ПК (win\unix)
- По возможности - чтобы была возможность подключаться и с другим языком - плюсы или питон например
- Возможность гонять информацию хотя бы как массив байт, хотя с определенной структурой было бы лучше

Собственно - хочется название технологии, которая ближе всех к указанным возможностям и минимальный пример работы, можно ссылкой на какой-нибудь репозиторий.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface

Comment: Ну, например, WCF.

Comment: Попробуйте сокеты

Comment: Cap'n Proto. Всё, вопрос можно закрывать как «порождающий бесконечные прения и дискуссии, основанные не на знаниях, а на мнениях».

Comment: @Arhad Cap'n Proto разве есть на C#?

Comment: @Qwertiy Серверный WCF не кроссплатформенный.

Comment: @Qwertiy а есть реальные приложения на других языках, которые умеют подключаться к WCF сервисам?

Comment: @Arhad названия технологии явно недостаточно же. И Cap'n Proto на c# с оффсайта ведёт на 404 к сожалению.

Comment: Сам репозиторий удалён, но есть зеркало: https://github.com/DeonHeyns/capnproto-net. Надеюсь, код рабочий.

/cc: @Raider

Comment: @Arhad там только сериализация.

Comment: @Raider, жаль. Тогда да, не подходит.

Comment: @Monk, java точно умеет. А вообще, там от способа сериализации зависит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [ZeroMQ](https://github.com/zeromq/netmq)
- [D-Bus](http://www.ndesk.org/DBusSharp)
- [Google Protocol Buffers](https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net) в связке с Named pipes или Sockets

В ссылках привожу биндинги/порты этих библиотек на C#.

Comment: `Named pipes или Sockets` -- что-то из этого способно пассивно ожидать соединения? Ну или активно, главное что, чтобы была возможность постучаться снаружи.

Comment: Конечно, у `NamedPipeServerStream` есть метод `WaitForConnectionAsync`, у `Socket` -- `ReceiveAsync`.

Comment: @Monk, разве named pipes кроссплатформенные?

Comment: @Qwertiy Named pipes есть и в .NET Core, и в Mono, да и вообще в *nix системах.

Answer (score 2):

Посмотри  [.Net Core, AppDomain, WCF, RPC маршалинг по Tcp/Ip свой велосипед](https://habrahabr.ru/post/323096/)

> Само решение очень близко с COM out process взаимодействием на
>   IDispatch.  Помню с удовольствием разбирался с внутренностями
>   TSocketConnection.
>
> Но, в отличие от Idispatch, используется перегрузка методов и
>   операторов, вызов Generic методов с выводом типов или с заданием
>   Generic аргументов. Поддержка методов расширений для классов,
>   находящихся в одной сборке и для Linq методов.
>
> Также поддержка асинхронных методов и подписка на события, ref и out
>   параметры, доступ по индексу [], поддержка итераторов в foreach.
>
> В отличии от Web Api, не нужно писать специально серверный код
>   Controller, Hub ы. Это близко к AppDomain c Remouting но, в отличие от
>   Remoting, каждый класс является аналогом MarshalByRefObject. То есть,
>   мы можем создать любой объект на стороне сервера и вернуть ссылку на
>   него (некоторые языки из чисел поддерживают только double).  При
>   вызове методов, напрямую сериализуются параметры только следующих
>   типов: числа, строки, дата, Guid и byte[]. Для остальных типов нужно
>   их создать на стороне сервера, а в параметрах методов уже передаются
>   ссылки на них.